# Image src has to be changed when used in different pages

Tags: html, laravel

The following is the HTML code to show the user image (avatar).

```
<img class="media-object" data-src="..." alt="{{$user->getName()}}"  src="uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
```

The images are in the following path :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\public\user\uploads\avatars
```

The image will show in the user profile page which is located in this path :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views\profile
```

But will not show in the Results page located in the below path, unless I change the `src="uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}"` to `src="user/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}"`  :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views
```

The above image code is located in a block of code to be included in many pages. So how can I fix the code to display the image in any page ?

Comment: Try adding your path "user/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" is asset() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the image source depending of what page is displayed.

```
<img class="media-object" data-src="..." alt="{{$user->getName()}}"        
   src="{{Request::path() === 'results' ?              
   '/user/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}' :             
   'uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}' }}">
```

Or

```
@if(Request::path() === 'results')
    <img class="media-object" data-src="..." alt="{{$user->getName()}}"  
    src="/user/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}"          
    style="width:150px; height:150px; 
    float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
@else
    <img class="media-object" data-src="..." alt="{{$user->getName()}}"  
    src="uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; 
    float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to apply the above for the following URL, but Ithe link is not working : @if(Request::path() === 'http://localhost/sharp/resources/views/profile/index.blade.php')

Comment: And not working with : @if(Request::path() === 'results') as well. I'm on Laravel 5.2

Comment: you don't need to use path with localhost, just use the url that displays the blade template (example - if the url is localhost/results, you can just put Request::path() === 'results')